# Add Country Manually in Customer A/c Details

Tags: magento-1.7, custom-options, code, customer

How can we set Country in Customer A/c Details Manually.

I am trying to execute code as following and

So Please Suggest Answer in that criteria :

```
 if (!$customer->getId()) {
                $customer->setEmail($email);
                $customer->setFirstname($name);
                $customer->setLastname($lastname);
                $customer->setPassword($password); 
}
```

Comment: the Problem is, that the country is saved in the address, so you need to change and save the address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @FabianBlechschmidt said - the customer entity doesn't have a country, the customer has an address, *which has a country*.

Depending on what address you wanted to update exactly, you could use something like this

```
$_customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId);
```

Then load the respective model,

```
$_addresssModel = $_customer->getDefaultBillingAddress();
$_addresssModel = $_customer->getDefaultShippingAddress();
```

Then set the country ID,

```
$_addresssModel->setCountryId('x')->save();
```

Comment: But How to get countryName using setCountryId ?

Comment: Get or Set? If you want to get the country name from the country ID, use `$countryName = Mage::getModel('directory/country')->load($countryCode)->getName();` - if you want to know a list of the country codes, see http://pastebin.com/97sBAB4J